# Privacy of search results between site collections

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Currently SharePoint allows one site collection to configure search results of search center in such way to access the indexed results of other site collections.

Is it possible to disallow other site collections to view the crawled data of a specific site collection ?

For example: If one site collection admins configures his search results, I don't want him to be able to access the search results from my own site collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Search results are security trimmed so the best solution I would suggest is breaking permission of your site(limit permission for other site collection admins for your site).

https://collab365.community/how-to-security-trim-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013/

One possible solution would be customizing display template(to check search result items URL, if url belongs to specific site collection, hide it, while this is site collection level means you need customize display template in target site collection which you want to hide the content).

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-display-templates-in-sharepoint-2013/